# TelephonyMagager.getDeviceId fails during BootTime on Galaxy S3

Tags: android, boot, galaxy, imei

My app uses `TelephonyMagager.getDeviceId()` to get the device's IMEI. I have implemented a service which starts during boot time. This works on Xperia (4.0.4) and Nexus (4.1.1) without problems.

On Galaxy S3 (running 4.1.1), `getDeviceId()` works fine if I start the service after boot time, but it returns `NULL` if I let the service start during boot time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the method description, the method returns null if device ID is not available. It seems like during boot time, for some reason, the device ID is indeed not available. I think you can possibly use [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html) blog post to meet your needs.